# HtAccess Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Please find my Laravel website URL below: www.webrox.ae

This website problem is that.. It opens /index.php and for all menu items like portfolio or hire us etc it it opens name/oservices/public/portfolio.. Something like this,....

Below is my htaccess file

Please Guide

```
#Alternate default index page
    DirectoryIndex www.webrox.ae/index.php
    # BlueHost.com 
    # .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
    # Do not change this line. 
    RewriteEngine on 
    # Change example.com to be your main domain. 
    # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
    # Don't change the following two lines. 
    # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?webrox.ae$ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oservice/public/ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oservice/public/$1 
    # Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
    # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
    # followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?webrox.ae$ 
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ webrox.ae/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.webrox\.ae$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/webrox\.ae\/" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share how did you use href attribute of `anchor` tag ( <a href="" ></a>) in your home page

Comment: Do you mean index.php? Its a lravel so please tell which path you are talking about

Comment: Try after removing /index.php from DirectoryIndex. It will take by default. I'm not sure but you can try

Comment: Try default htaccess that generated while creating your bolg

Answer (score 0):

Change the line from

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oservice/public/ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ webrox.ae/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ webrox.ae [L]
```

And add the line

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```